# How to name the filenames of a database and set its location in Visual Studio 2015 Database project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

By selecting "Publish" in the context menu of a VS 2015 Database project, I can create a script, which contains all the necessary commands to deploy the database to the SQL Server ("xyz.publish.sql").

The database name and its paths in this script are declared as variables:

```
:setvar DatabaseName "myDatabase"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "myDatabase"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "D:\Databases\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "D:\Databases\"
```

also the filenames seems to be automatically generated:

```
PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf')...
```

Where can I set the paths and the filenames? I don't want "_Primary" to be attached at the filenames and the paths need an additional sub-folder.

If I change in the publish script, my changes will probably be overwritten the next time when this script will be generated by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a pre-deployment script to the project which detaches the database, moves/renames the files, then reattaches the database using the new files.

```
-- detach db before moving physical files
USE [master]
GO
exec sp_detach_db @dbname = N'$(DatabaseName)'
GO

-- enable xp_cmdshell
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1  -- 0 = Disable , 1 = Enable
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

-- move physical files
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'MOVE "$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf", "C:\$(DatabaseName)\$(DatabaseName).mdf"'
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'MOVE "$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf", "C:\$(DatabaseName)\$(DatabaseName)_log.ldf"'
GO

-- reattach db with new filepath
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] ON 
(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = 'C:\$(DatabaseName)\$(DatabaseName).mdf'),
(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = 'C:\$(DatabaseName)\$(DatabaseName)_log.ldf')
FOR ATTACH
GO

-- disable xp_cmdshell
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0  -- 0 = Disable , 1 = Enable
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

USE [$(DatabaseName)];
GO
```

Some notes on this:

- I hardcoded C:\ as the new location for the files for simplicity. You're better off creating a SQLCMD variable to store this path.
- If `xp_cmdshell 'MOVE ...` fails, it will do so silently. To keep my answer simple I did not include any error checking, but you can roll your own by simply inserting the results of xp_cmdshell in a temp table. See [How to capture the error output from xp_cmdshell in SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/how-to-capture-error-output-from-xp_cmds/).
- You may run into permissions problems with the `xp_cmdshell 'MOVE ...` command. In that case, you may need to adjust the permissions of the source and target paths in the MOVE statement. You may also need to run the command as a different user -- see [here (Permissions section)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175046(v=SQL.110).aspx) or [here](http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/03/how-do-you-secure-sql-server-instance.html) for starters.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it in your way a few minutes ago, but added a post-deployment script and use "ALTER Database ... FILENAME=...".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will be changed but that's the way it works. You have to change the script. The other thing you can do is not specify the locations in which SQL Server will use the default ones for the instance - but that too involves changing the script.