# Visual Studio 2013 database project - deployment / publishing - filegroup PRIMARY

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, deployment, publish, database-project

Traditionally I have created simple databases using SQL Server Management Studio, then taken a backup and restored to an empty database online. That is the preferred way of my hosting server.

I recently started using Visual Studio 2013 database project options because I prefer that environment. I used this http://sanderstechnology.com/2013/schema-modelling-with-visual-studio-2013-preview/12336/#.VijncNKFO71 as my guide.

There are differences - I don't have the post deploy scripts option so I have created databases using PUBLISH which seems to be fine. There is one quirk which differs in all the examples I've looked at. When I publish, it creates the database with the name I chose and appends `_PRIMARY`. In the database properties it shows the database name but above that it shows `FileGroup = Primary`, so I'm assuming that is why? When I view the DB via VS2013 or SQL Server Management Studio, it just shows the DB name but if I want to attach the DB to a project I have to attach the `_PRIMARY.mdf` file.

In my ignorance I am assuming the `_PRIMARY` is a wrapper around the database? I am wondering why VS2013 does that and if deploying the way I do, as explained above, is this going to cause issues? Or am I simply doing everything wrong..

Comment: I answered your question but I'm not clear on your statement `When I view the DB via VS2013 or SQL Server Management Studio, it just shows the DB name but if I want to attach the DB to a project I have to attach the _PRIMARY.mdf file.` If this is a problem, can you provide more details, perhaps even screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database project automatically creates a filegroup named PRIMARY for the database. This becomes the default filegroup unless you change it (see project properties > Project Settings > Database Settings > Operational tab), but typically you don't need to.

The database project automatically uses the filegroup name in the primary data file's name, for example `MyDatabase_PRIMARY.mdf`. This is a good convention to follow in case you need to have multiple data files (ex: `MyDatabase_SECONDARY.ndf`, `MyDatabase_FILEDATA.ndf`, etc).

What VS is doing is perfectly fine. Data file names are arbitrary anyway. If you do need more control over how the data file is named then read [How to name the filenames of a database and set its location in Visual Studio 2015 Database project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091368/how-to-name-the-filenames-of-a-database-and-set-its-location-in-visual-studio-20/32099677)

I also suggest reading more about files and filegroups in [Files and Filegroups Architecture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Hi Keith - sorry for the delay in answering you - I assumed I would receive a notification when a reply was posted :(... Sorry again. When I look through the databases using SSMS the database name shows Without the primary appendage. I thank you for the answer, it supplies some good links. What I did for peace of mind was create a new DB using the schema from the project - I hadn't done that before and quite liked that functionality specially as it keeps the 'clone' db's data in tact - so now I don't care what gets appended to the original db.